# While loop without destroying previous refernce

Tags: java, android, while-loop

In the following loop `marker` is a list which is is iterated through and each item is drawn on the canvas. However as the loop progresses I believe that the previous references are destroyed. How can I create a unique instance for each run of the loop?

```
            //Draw AR markers in reverse order since the last drawn should be the closest
        ListIterator<Marker> iter = collection.listIterator(collection.size());
        while (iter.hasPrevious()) { 
            Marker marker = iter.previous();
            marker.draw(canvas);
        }
```

I've tried the following but to no avail. The loop reaches the second item then has a NoSuchElementException.

```
        while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
        int i = 0;
        try {

            Marker marker = iter.previous();
            marker.draw(canvas);
            ++i;
            System.out.println("Item number 1 " + i);
            Marker marker1 = iter.next();
            marker1.draw(canvas);
            ++i;
            ... repeated up to marker7 then catching the NoSuchElementException.
```

Comment: Your first while is doing exactly what you want. It does not overwrite the previous reference, but is creating a new one each iteration. What exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: @RohitJain Once everything is drawn to the canvas I take a screenshot of everything that's currently on the canvas. Only the first marker is ever present all of the rest of the ones show up on the screen for the user to use-however they don't seem to be present on the actual canvas to be captured in a screenshot.

Comment: How are you populating your `List`? That is the source of the problems you might be getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the issue.

You are not creating new `Marker` objects, just reading it from an iterable `Collection`. The original collection (and probably other objects) contains references to the objects your are looping through, so they are not destroyed.

Your second code only checks for `iter.hasPrevious()` at the beginning of the loop, but it is doing many operations. If there are not enough elements in the `Collection`/iterator, then you get that exception when trying to reach for an element that does not exist (for example, doing `iter.previous()` after `iter` has reached the first element).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue. You're exactly right. In another section I was clearing a cache to increase performance but this also meant wiping some markers from the canvas.